# VPN-connected network passthrough using ssh

Tags: ssh, vpn

I have an imac at home which is my *main machine*. I also have an ubuntu pc on the same **LAN**. I connect to my *work network* through **VPN** from my main machine (imac). I also sometimes connect to my ubuntu machine through ssh from my main machine. However, some resources on the ubuntu machine need to access my work network (like accessing sw licenses, git server, etc.). Please look at the image below:

[block diagram of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45yv1.jpg)

How can I make my ubuntu machine to use the work-network through the vpn on my main machine (imac) when I connect to this ubuntu through SSH? I hope I explained my problem properly. TIA.

Comment: I guess it is just a matter of adding the correct routes.